# Why does the presence of primary key on the table significantly enhance the performance of column-store indexes?

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes, columnstore

I was trying to see the kind of performance gains column-store indexes can provide on a table. The table has about a 3.7 million rows, 11 columns and is stored as a heap (i.e without a primary key). I create a column-store index on the table and run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Area], [Family],
    AVG([Global Sales Value]) AS [Average GlobalSalesValue],
    COUNT([Projected Sales])
FROM 
    dbo.copy_Global_Previous5FullYearSales
WHERE 
    [Year] > 2012  
GROUP BY 
    [Area], [Family]
```

The create table statement is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[copy_Global_Previous5FullYearSales]
(
    [SBU] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [Year] [INT] NULL,
    [Global Sales Value] [MONEY] NULL,
    [Area] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Sub Area] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Projected Sales] [MONEY] NULL,
    [Family] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Sub Family 1] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Sub Family 2] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [NVARCHAR](40) NULL,
    [rowguid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The performance gains I get from column-store index in this case is negligible. The query with the column-store index runs nearly as slow as the original query without an index, in some cases, even slower, even though batch mode is processing is used too.

Surprisingly, when I create an ever increasing primary key - ID on the existing table and rebuild the column-store index, I get a 15X improvement on the CPU time and a 3X improvement on the elapsed time.

I don't understand how the addition of a primary key could affect query performance for column-store indexes which store the data in a compressed format anyway. Also primary keys only change the ordering of the pages which in this case, would be none.

Below is the execution plan [image: Execution Plan]

Comment: A side note: a heap table does not imply there is no primary key. You can create a non-clustered primary key without problems (and that actually makes sense for some types of primary keys)

Comment: @Martin - Hi, I've added the create table statement. And the plan is complete, its just snipped separately. So, after the sort, there is a stream aggregate.

Comment: @user2673722 thanks, yes I realised that point on the plans. Are the plans identical for both the heap and the CI case? Did you look at number of reads in both cases and size taken up by the index in both cases?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Alright, I'm pretty new to databases and SQL, I'll probably look into this. But currently this table, just has that primary key and a uniqueidentifier, rowguid.

Comment: @Martin - yes, the execution plans are exactly the same. Alos, here is a summary of the logical reads in [Heap/CI] format - 80555/14646, physical reads - 0/1

Comment: So it's reading 6 times as many as pages then.

Comment: @Martin - Also, Index size - 90104/466KB --- I didn't notice the index sizes, any clue why one is so huge ?

Comment: @Martin - Yeah, but i don't understand how a primary index changes things so much..

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? What did you use to determine the sizes?

Comment: EXEC sys.sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.copy_Global_Previous5FullYearSales' -- for the heap table and got the same result when I tried to cross check it with a code from here [link](http://basitaalishan.com/2012/07/06/find-the-size-of-index-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Author probably wanted to say "presence of clustered index" rather than "presence of primary key" as this is more relevant to the subject. Well, I ran series of experiments and never at any time there was any difference with performance between cases when clustered index was present or absent. Most likely author's experimental environment was not accurate and some other things influenced performance (but not the presence of clustered index)

Comment: Author says "The query with the column-store index runs nearly as slow as the original query without an index, in some cases, even slower". This brings additional doubts that experiment was set up correctly. It looks like only partial info was presented. Can you please provide a script, which creates your columnstore index? Do you have any other indexes on the same table? Please provide them as well.

Answer (score 4):

The presence of a a key changes how the columnstore is **built**. Because the builder gets its input in order the resulted segments are better candidates for segment elimination. Read more at [Ensuring Your Data is Sorted or Nearly Sorted by Date to Benefit from Date Range Elimination](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5718.ensuring-your-data-is-sorted-or-nearly-sorted-by-date-to-benefit-from-date-range-elimination.aspx):

> The most common type of filter in data warehouse queries is by date. Columnstore segment elimination helps you skip entire one-million-row segments if the system can determine that no rows qualify, simply by looking at the minimum and maximum values for a column in a segment. So you usually will want to make sure that your segments are sorted, or nearly sorted, by date, so date filters can be executed as fast as possible.

Your order is by `ID` but I'm pretty sure that causes functional dependencies side-effects.

Comment: Hi, I order it by ID, but I how would it change the way pages are ordered, since the ID column just adds a unique number to each column...Also, I don't even use the ID column when creating column-store indexes.

Comment: @user2673722 If you still have both copies of the table there are some queries here you can use to see the segment boundaries and segment elimination http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/exploring-columnstore-index-metadata-segment-distribution-and-elimination-behaviors/

Comment: @user2673722 read the articles linked, they explain why having the ID matters, *even if you never use it*.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - I couldn't really find anything useful from the link you suggested..it suggests that when the data is sorted by say Date, using clustered keys, then segment elimination becomes easy; That's understandable, but in my case, I create an additional column called ID, which doesn't speed up anything I think

Comment: @Martin - The link you provided was very helpful. It would be great, if you could add it as an answer below, so I can indicate it was the right answer