# Physical reads with column-store more than that in a heap

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes, columnstore

Below is the link explaining my the table and the situation:

[Why does the presence of primary key on the table significantly enhance the performance of column-store indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432934/why-does-the-presence-of-primary-key-on-the-table-significantly-enhance-the-perf)

When comparing the two situations, one where the query is run using the column-store index and the other, where the query is run on a simple heap. When I compare the two results, I observe that even though the query with the column-store performs better than the other case, when simply run on a heap. 
But, the query using the column-store index involves a physical read(1) while the original one doesn't.

Both the queries have the same execution plan. Also, I run the queries in both the situations in warm and cold buffers. In a cold buffer, the original query requires 4 physical reads, while in a warn buffer, it required 0 physical reads. 
The behavior of the query using the column-store indexes however remains the same. Is there any particular reason behind this?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - Thanks for editing it. My bad, I missed that.

Comment: I have observed similar things. SQL Server sometimes is unable to make full use of cache memory to cache a columnstore index even when space is available to cache the entire index. I don't know the reason for this and I think it's a bug. It's hard to reproduce. Goes away when the server reboots for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot has changed in SQL Server 2012, including new DMVs, new memory management and the addition of COLUMNSTORE indexes.

The problem: Query using a column store index results in physical read (data cache miss).

Assumptions: SQL Server 2012, clustered column store index

Disclaimer: This is not an answer, but an attempt to further the discussion.

The column store (new in SQL Server 2012) caches column store index objects (compressed) and this memory is separate from the buffer pool.

Memory allocation is simplified in SQL Server 2012 by the new any-page allocator in SQLOS, replacing the single-page 8 KB and multi-page allocators (for > 8 KB requests).

Both the buffer pool and column store cache allocate memory via the any-page allocator.  However, the buffer pool caches data pages and column store caches compressed column store index objects.

A possible explanation for the data cache miss is memory pressure on the buffer pool from the column store memory allocation may cause "page flushing."

I use the book **SQL Server 2012 internals** as a reference.  In addition, this article explaining how COLOMNSTORE index uses memory in SQL Server 2012:
[Clustered Columnstore Indexes – part 38 (“Memory Structures”)](http://www.nikoport.com/2014/08/11/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-38-memory-structures/)